# internal memory

Tags: internal-storage, insufficient-memory

My phones internal memory is only 2GB. I only have very few apps like facebook, viber, etc.

When I bought my phone I installed a lot of apps and games but did not have any problems with the internal memory. All of my apps, photos, musicc etc are saved in the SD card. How come I now have a very low memory left internally when I have a lot less apps and games compared to before?

Comment: Bigger apps? Storing more data? When I look back a few years, an app of 1 MB size was considered big. Today it sometimes seems that's the minimum size you can get.

Answer (score 1):

Various crash logs tend to clog up internal memory on older devices.  You can try clearing them out by doing the following:

1. In Dialer app dial the following: ***#9900#**  Note that this may not work on all devices (specifically on tablets, since they don't have a dialer to begin with.)  Some devices require you to tap the "call" button, while on others the code should start running the moment you hit the last "#" sign.
2. This will open up the SysDump utility as shown here:
   [image]
3. Tap the "Delete dumpstate/logcat" button, and exit out of the app.

This should hopefully free up some internal storage space.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a cleanup job ?? The internal storage is also called sdcard. Cleanup first, cache included. Then make sure that most or all apps are moved/installed to external SD.

Answer (score 0):

First off, be careful in what you mean by "memory" here. You've got RAM that's used by running and cached but inactive apps, and you've got internal storage. I'll assume you're talking about internal storage here.

Apps don't necessarily get stored to the SD card (or "external storage" under KitKat). Some apps **cannot** be stored there. **All** apps keep a portion of themselves in internal storage. Apps also store data, including their own caches, in internal storage. Then there are the ad add-ons that may be consuming more space than in the past.

Start first by clearing app caches. Since you're running low on internal storage, I suggest doing this by hand. You may also find some apps you didn't realize you had. As you go through each one, also see if you can move any of them to the SD card. Don't go crazy over this, because some of them won't be worth the time, but it could help.

If all else fails, it might be time for a factory reset and reload of everything.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rundown of steps that can help remedy your problem:

1. Open up downloads from app drawer, delete all incomplete downloads.
2. Use a file browser and move all music, movies, videos, photos, and documents to ext SD card.
3. Open up *settings/app manager/all*, scroll to `Media Storage`. Force stop first, then clear data.°
4. Use a cleaning app such as *CCLEANER* OR *CM SECURITY*; to remove old, useless left over data.
5. Perform a factory reset, backup essential data first.
6. Go into recovery wipe *cache* and *dalvik-cache*, reboot.
7. Install custom recovery and custom ROM for your device.

`° This will not erase any existing files, this will force the system to rescan your device. Any entries for non-existing (left over) files will be removed`